# Autotests for ios applications in browserstack. Two-factor auth(

Tags: ios, testflight, browserstack, two-factor-authentication, autotest

In browserstack I have installed ios app using testflight. But this method requires two-factor auth. This is a problem for application autotest. What are the ways to run autotests in browserstack?

Comment: long shot, but did you get anywhere with this? I've run into the same issue

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, support for installing applications via TestFlight is not available on App Automate. Are you encountering issued while installing applications via TestFlight on App Live? It would be great if you can share a screenshot.

Comment: this should not be an answer